# How to make Kaleidoscope diff app's ksdiff work with Mercurial / hg

Tags: mercurial, kaleidoscope

[Kaleidoscope](http://kaleidoscope.app) is a really useful diff tool for Mac. It integrates with `git difftool` by adding this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
    cmd = ksdiff --partial-changeset --relative-path \"$MERGED\" -- \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    prompt = false
```

**How do you make it work with Mercurial / `hg`?**

I found [this documentation for Mercurial's Extdiff extension](https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/ExtdiffExtension), which references some `kdiff3` thing that does not appear to take the same args as `ksdiff`. When Kaleidoscope opens, it's a really frustrating UI that makes you click down into directories (deal breaker for those Java devs out there ✌️), and it does not have the useful sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction to use Kaleidoscope  with Mercurial / hg can be found in the Kaleidoscope > Integrations window.

[image: Kaleidoscope Mercurial Integration]

Add this to your ~/.hgrc:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.ksdiff = /usr/local/bin/ksdiff
opts.ksdiff = --changeset --wait --filelist

[ui]
merge = Kaleidoscope

[merge-tools]
Kaleidoscope.executable = /usr/local/bin/ksdiff
Kaleidoscope.args = --merge --output $output --base $base -- $local $other
```

Comment: @aaronstacy please let us know if you have any problems with the integrations steps for mercurial: hello@kaleidoscope.app

Comment: much cleaner, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: [@catlan's approach is cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76474224/5377)**

Add this to your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.difftool = bash
opts.difftool = -c 'for f in `find $1 -type f`; do ksdiff --partial-changeset --relative-path ${f#$1/} -- ${0}${f#$1} $f; done'
```

If you can add a script to your `$PATH`, you could have a cleaner message in the Kaleidoscope title bar by using something like [this ruby script from gregawoods](https://gist.github.com/gregawoods/5358193).